# Magento 2: How do I join sales_order_grid table to sales_order_item table?

Tags: price, sales-order, sales, sales-quote

```
select *  from sales_order_item t1
inner join quote_item t2 on t1.quote_item_id=t2.item_id
inner join sales_order_grid t3 on t1.order_id=t3.entity_id
```

I am trying to pull a `report` along with `each items price` and that's what I got but it seems like it isn't the correct `join table`.

Can anyone help me with getting a `correct table join`?

Comment: What's your magento version?